# NPN cannot be found

Tags: node.js

I have installed NPN on my machine by i am getting the following error

> curl https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh

```
No command 'npn' found, did you mean:
 Command 'npg' from package 'netdisco-backend' (universe)
 Command 'nn' from package 'nn' (universe)
 Command 'npm' from package 'npm' (universe)
 Command 'xpn' from package 'xpn' (universe)
npn: command not found
```

Comment: Ha Ha - made the same mistake. Great question. +1 (would vote to reopen, but there's no ambiguity about this being off topic)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you mean `npm`.

Try that.

Comment: omg.. i cant believe i have been typing npn :(

Comment: (I know I'm not supposed to say this in a comment. But I can't help it.) Me Too!!!